# openvpn server on localhost on Android

Tags: android, vpn, openvpn

My OpenVPN tunnel is subject of tunneling via another (custom) tunneling software .
So client's ovpn profile points to localhost(for example 192.168.0.100) as ovpn remote.

Client profile appends localhost and remote endpoint of custom tunnel to route table, to exclude it from VPN traffic. Like this :

```
--begin of test.ovpn--------------
remote 192.168.0.100
proto tcp
port 1194

route 192.168.0.100  255.255.255.255 net_gateway
route <ip of custom tunnel server>  255.255.255.255 net_gateway
--end of test.ovpn--------------
```

It's works like a charm under Debian on desktop, but don't works on Android with "OpenVPN Connection".

Custom tunnel on Android even don't detect any attempts to connect on local port. "OpenVPN Connection" report retry because timeout .

I suppose it's related to some peculiarities of routing on Android , but I can't figure-out what exactly.

Will be grateful for some hints.
Thanks.

Comment: direct connection OpenVPN client -> OpenVPN server on android works fine (e.g. without tunneling via custom tunnel).

Answer (score -1):

It's look like "OpenVPN Connection" application ignores routes section.
Because "OpenVPN for Android" do the trick, and all works as expected.